# Input error on " = " Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

the following code refuses to compile.
Please be gracious ,  I have been working with Haskell for 1.5 weeks. So just a beginner.

```
                       name = (mod ( tag + x + (div ( 31 * m )  12 )) 7 )
```

I have parse error on input "=" It regards to the following line:

`name = (mod ( tag + x + (div ( 31 * m )  12 )) 7 )`

I do not know what is wrong on/in that line. I have been working with other languages but Haskell is kind of specific.

Comment: Can you explain the problem which this function must solve (in plain English)?

Comment: Editing answers is not the right way to reply to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you wanted, but it's just syntax error. Maybe you wanted to check for equality (then use `==` instead of `=`). But it may not be the case, because then return type should be `Bool`, not `String`.
Also, the example looks strange, because not all arguments of function `weekday` are used in its definition.

### Update

I suspect, your code should be like this:

```
weekday :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String
weekday jahr monat tag =
  let name = (mod ( tag + x + (div ( 31 * m )  12 )) 7 )
  in
    case name of
    0 -> "Sonntag"
    1 -> "Montag"
    2 -> "Dienstag" 
    3 -> "Mittwoch"
    4 -> "Donnerstag"
    5 -> "Freitag"
    6 -> "Samstag"
  where                        
    y = jahr - ( div ( 14 - monat )  12 )   
    x = y + ( div y 4 ) - ( div y 100 ) + ( div y 400 )
    m = monat + (12 * ( div ( 14 - monat ) 12 )) - 2
```

It even does work (although I didn't check result): http://ideone.com/YAKXTU

You should learn a bit more about meanings of essential Haskell constructs `let` and `where`, and there is a good book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" which I recommend. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` bindings to introduce names in Haskell.

```
weekday jahr monat tag = <function body>
  where name = (mod ( tag + x + (div ( 31 * m )  12 )) 7 )
```

That is, you need to define your variables in a `where` clause to the function. You can read more about `where` clauses for example in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where).

About your second question: You *can* use tabs in Haskell code, it's just that in Haskell code, we rarely talk about "indented blocks of code" – the place where tabs are good. We mostly try to align function arguments, and spaces are way better for alignment.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I assumed OP in an imperative fashion started to write a function body where the first statement is an assignment, and then wanted to write further statements on the following lines but the very first line failed to compile. (Or perhaps OP cut out the following lines since they were irrelevant to the problem at hand.) If you look at the edit history of the post, there has been periods of more and less information available.

Comment: Yes. If I remember correctly, I wrote that comment before first edit. BTW, the message was deciphered and can be found in my answer.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Yeah, I saw that the question was successfully answered. Thanks! (The only thing I would do differently would be to define `name` in the `where` clause with the other names, but that's just a stylistic choice.)